# Controls without views for globals functions in asp.net MVC (with Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The well described model of View/Controller/Model is quite clear when it comes to object (say a book) update/delete/save etc., but how do you organize the common code such as populating drop down lists (from db)?

I use jQuery ajax to call control's action, but in cases such as getting the arrays for drop down lists, I feel like these should not reside in the same BookController.

Can I have a Controller without the matching view for these purposes only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `ViewModel` is data for a `View` to render.  It sounds like you understand that.  When Ajax calls for Data, I think it makes more sense for the controller for the view be responsible for creating another `ViewModel` and returning it as Json for the rendered view.  If mutliple views need to retrieve a list of Books, should call `/Books/AjaxList` (bad method name example), just like any view under `/Books`.  Seperating the responsibility of creating a `ViewModel` based on Ajax or not Ajax doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. First of all, i don't use ViewModels. I just use View/Model/Controller. Secondly, my question was more to do with other information that is coming from the database and is used in the form, such as categories list, user's attributes etc etc...which doesn't belong in the Book Model (or ViewModel). So, would you have a separate controller for these (without the view)?

Comment: When a view/partial view uses the @Model namespace.classOrInterface you are defining a Model for a View (ViewModel).  My preference for returning a model for consumption by a View or Ajax request is a ViewModel (becuase the consumer is a View of some sort).  Sorry if my nomenclature was confusion.

Comment: Why aren't all the required data for the view to render being passed in Model or in a single Ajax request (Model) at the beginning?

Comment: Because it's just not how this app works. Many elements on the page are interactive and depends on other elements. All I am asking is how do you organize these helper actions. I am leaning towards putting it in a separate controller.

Comment: Erik, I see what you meant. I am new to MVC - I will use ViewModel and load as much data as I can off the bat. Will mark yours as answer.